# What's the alternative to pandas chain indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, chain

I'm taking an online class to learn python and the instructor taught us that chain indexing was not a good idea.  However, he failed to tell is the appropriate alternative to use.

Suppose I have a Pandas data frame with rows indexed as `['1', '2', '3']` and columns with names `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

What's the appropriate alternative to using the command `df['1']['a']` to extract the value found in the first row and first column?

Comment: Please see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 13):

Use [multi-axis indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing), e.g.

```
df.loc['a', '1']
```

When you use  `df['1']['a']`, you are first accessing the series object `s = df['1']`, and then accessing the series element `s['a']`, resulting in two `__getitem__` calls, both of which are heavily overloaded (handle a lot of scenarios, like slicing, boolean mask indexing, and so on).

It's much more efficient to use the `df.loc` indexer.