# Binarizing pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

```
mean radius mean texture    mean perimeter  mean area   mean smoothness mean compactness    mean concavity  mean concave points mean symmetry   mean fractal dimension  ... worst texture   worst perimeter worst area  worst smoothness    worst compactness   worst concavity worst concave points    worst symmetry  worst fractal dimension classification
0   17.99   10.38   122.80  1001.0  0.11840 0.27760 0.3001  0.14710 0.2419  0.07871 ... 17.33   184.60  2019.0  0.1622  0.6656  0.7119  0.2654  0.4601  0.11890 0
1   20.57   17.77   132.90  1326.0  0.08474 0.07864 0.0869  0.07017 0.1812  0.05667 ... 23.41   158.80  1956.0  0.1238  0.1866  0.2416  0.1860  0.2750  0.08902 0
2   19.69   21.25   130.00  1203.0  0.10960 0.15990 0.1974  0.12790 0.2069  0.05999 ... 25.53   152.50  1709.0  0.1444  0.4245  0.4504  0.2430  0.3613  0.08758 0
3   11.42   20.38   77.58   386.1   0.14250 0.28390 0.2414  0.10520 0.2597  0.09744 ... 26.50   98.87   567.7   0.2098  0.8663  0.6869  0.2575  0.6638  0.17300 0
4   20.29   14.34   135.10  1297.0  0.10030 0.13280 0.1980  0.10430 0.1809  0.05883 ... 16.67   152.20  1575.0  0.1374  0.2050  0.4000  0.1625  0.2364  0.07678 0
```

Suppose I have a pandas dataFrame that looks like above.
I want to binarize (change to 0 or 1) of the `mean radius` column if it the value is higher than `12.0`.

What I've tried is

`data_df.loc[data_df["mean radius"] > 12.0] = 0`

But this gave me a weird result.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted to change the whole column to 1 and 0, you could modify your code slightly to:

```
# 0 if greater than 12, 1 otherwise
data_df["mean_radius"] = (data_df["mean radius"] <= 12.0).astype(int)
```

If you just wanted to change the columns where the radius was greater than 12 to 0 (leaving the values less than 12 unchanged):

```
# only change the values > 12
# this method is discouraged, see edit below
data_df[data_df["mean radius"] > 12.0]["mean radius"] = 0
```

**Edit**

As @jp_data_analysis pointed out, [chained indexing is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253181/5858851). The preferred way to do the second operation is multi-axis indexing, reproduced here from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472165/5858851) below:

```
# only change the values > 12
data_df.loc[data_df["mean radius"] > 12.0, "mean radius"] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to store the binarized result to a new column, do I simply have to do `data_df['new column'] = data_df[column_name] < cutoff` ?

Comment: Yup exactly. But you'll probably have to call `.astype(int)` if you want 1's and 0's (see my update). `data_df[column_name] < cutoff` will return booleans (`True` and `False`).

Comment: The Boolean -> int series method is good. But I would discourage chained indexing (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253181/9209546).

Comment: @jp_data_analysis thanks for the info! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the column as well, as so:

```
data_df.loc[data_df["mean radius"] > 12.0, "mean radius"] = 0
```

Comment: If I want to make the opposite case (less than 12.0) to 1, do I just have to write a new line with a different condition?

Comment: @Dawn17 Yes. Alternatively, set it to 1 to begin with and just specify 0 condition. But only if these 2 scenarios cover all cases (e.g. no NaN).

Answer (score 0):

By using `mask`

```
data_df["mean radius"]=data_df["mean radius"].mask(data_df["mean radius"] > 12.0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to change the values to Boolean (TRUE and FALSE) and then multiply by 1 to binarize it into 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. Here is how it is done:

`data_df['mean_radius'] = (data_df['mean radius'] > 12.0)*1`

`print(data_df['mean_radius'])`

This code will add a new column called mean_radius with binarized values. Let me know if this helps.