# Inplace Modifying a Column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

**Edit:** I've since realised that when accessing with .loc I get no error but a warning, so the code actually works.

I have a dataset that needs some cleaning. One of the things I needed to do was to remove all transactions of more than 50000kn.
It happens that the cost `bruto_prihod` is in string format and that the transactions `transakcija_sifra` span multiple rows.
An additional inconvenience is that the decimal formatting is with a comma (we use a decimal comma in Croatian) instead of a dot.

This is my code before the task:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    diversus = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\dagejev\Desktop\excel\diversus4_saved.csv", encoding="cp1252", sep=";")

    df = diversus.copy()

    df_filter = df[(df['faza'] == 'A') &
                   ( (df['grupa_id'] == 'W ODIJELO') | (df['grupa_id'] == 'ODIJELO') ) &
                   ( (df['vp_kupac_id']!= 591) & (df['vp_kupac_id']!= 333) & (df['vp_kupac_id']!= 332) ) &
                   ( (df['brand_naziv'] == 'JOOP') | (df['brand_naziv'] == 'JOOP!') ) &
                   (df['vrsta_robe']=='ROBA') &
                   (df['divizija'] == 'MEN')]
    print('df: ', len(df), 'filtered: ', len(df_filter))
```

Here's the relevant part:

```
#This is what I tried first

df_filter['bruto_prihod'] = df_filter['bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')
```

However, it doesn't work:

```
C:\Users\dagejev\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

And neither does the suggested alternative:

```py
    df_filter[:,'bruto_prihod'] = df_filter['bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-82-0e27bdc0e78f> in <module>
    ----> 1 df_filter[:,'bruto_prihod'] = df_filter['bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
       3368         else:
       3369             # set column
    -> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
       3371 
       3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
       3443 
       3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
    -> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
       3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
       3447 

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
       3659 
       3660         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
    -> 3661         if broadcast and key in self.columns and value.ndim == 1:
       3662             if (not self.columns.is_unique or
       3663                     isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex)):

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __contains__(self, key)
       3918     @Appender(_index_shared_docs['contains'] % _index_doc_kwargs)
       3919     def __contains__(self, key):
    -> 3920         hash(key)
       3921         try:
       3922             return key in self._engine

    TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

**But this chain indexing does** ([which is supposedly always bad to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774184/how-and-when-to-use-chain-indexing-in-python-pandas)):

```py
    df_filter[:]['bruto_prihod'] = df_filter['bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')
```

Furthermore, this doesn't work:

```py
    df_filter['bruto_prihod'] = pd.to_numeric(df_filter['bruto_prihod'])
```

But this does:

```py
df_filter[:]['bruto_prihod'] = pd.to_numeric(df_filter['bruto_prihod'])
```

Why is that so? **Why do I have to chain indexes for my in place assignment to work?**

Also, if someone is interested, this is how I grouped the transactions:

```py
df_filter.groupby('transakcija_sifra').agg({'bruto_prihod':np.sum}).sort_values('bruto_prihod', ascending=False)
```

Comment: use `.loc` instead of chaining: `df_filter.loc[:, 'bruto_prihod'] = df_filter.loc[:, 'bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')`. But it should work without the chaining or the `.loc`, that's weird. What do you mean by doesn't work, do you get an error message?

Comment: Already tried, here's the error: C:\Users\dagejev\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @Dan Yes, I meant I get an error message by doesn't work.

Comment: Please always include the exact error message in your question. Also when are you doing the `groupby`? Before or after this error? And are you assigning the grouped series somewhere?

Comment: You really get that error on a line that uses `.loc` on the LHS? That makes no sense, the error itself is telling you to use `.loc`...

Comment: @Dan I am doing the `groupby` after everything else. I have no error when I chain indexes. I will go edit the answer to include errors. I am just viewing the `groupby` currently.

Comment: @Dan sorry, forgot to rerun all cells, I get a lengthy error when using .loc which ends with: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Comment: btw - I have a feeling that `df_filter[:]` will create a copy, so this probably isn't really inplace.

Comment: @Dan I updated the post with all the errors. I double-checked and .loc[:, 'bruto_prihod'] doesn't work.

Comment: In your edit you have `df_filter[:,'bruto_prihod'] = df_filter['bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')` which is not what I suggested. You have left off the `.loc` which is the whole point. It should be `df_filter.loc[: ,'bruto_prihod'] = df_filter.loc[: 'bruto_prihod'].str.replace(',','.')`

Comment: @Dan I tried both. And tried to change the right side to loc as well, all combinations. I get a different error each time.

Comment: Post the error using `.loc` on both sides. Not the bad syntax you have posted. Also, the first way you have it, you are not getting an error. Just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warning you can use explicit [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df_filter = df[(df['faza'] == 'A') &
               ( (df['grupa_id'] == 'W ODIJELO') | (df['grupa_id'] == 'ODIJELO') ) &
               ( (df['vp_kupac_id']!= 591) & (df['vp_kupac_id']!= 333) & (df['vp_kupac_id']!= 332) ) &
               ( (df['brand_naziv'] == 'JOOP') | (df['brand_naziv'] == 'JOOP!') ) &
               (df['vrsta_robe']=='ROBA') &
               (df['divizija'] == 'MEN')].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like better code, but I got no warning.